# Write Out Class Methods to Log File

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have a need to write out a Class's Methods to a log file. This needs to be done so the end user can verify the calculations within the Methods are correct.

So, 2 questions:

1. Can this be done?
2. Do you need to see any of my code to accomplish this? C# or VB will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Type.GetMethods()` to obtain all the methods of a class (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/td205ybf).
You will obtain an array of `System.Reflection.MethodInfo[]` containing all the info you can need about a Method (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.methodinfo)

Answer (score 0):

> This needs to be done so the end user can verify the calculations within the Methods are correct.

This seems like an onerous task to me, is there a reason you want end-users having a view on the internals of your code?

If you want the parameters and the results of the methods being logged I recommend using [Postsharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) in particular the [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://doc.postsharp.net/##T_PostSharp_Aspects_OnMethodBoundaryAspect). But as I said I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: m.Edmonson, the reason the user needs it is because the calculations are from the end user and have been translated into a tool for him. There is also a very large financial and regulatory impact on the numbers being right. The tool will be crunching through a lot of data, so it is very beneficial for him to see the formulas so we can pinpoint where the the calculations are not correct.....I shoulda put this in my initial question...